# Python: My Chat server is not responding when i start it up

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, server

I have a problem. My server is not responding when i start it. Can you please help me? Thanks for every idea!
And tell me if it's good idea to use Tkinter for server, thanks!
Here's code:

```
import socket
import thread
import time
from Tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog as simpledialog

klienti = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "10.0.0.32"
port = 9999

okno = Tk()
okno.title("Chat Server")
okno.geometry("700x460")
okno.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

Log = Text(okno, bg="white", height="5", width="70", font="Arial",)
Log.config(state=DISABLED)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(okno, command=Log.yview)
Log["yscrollcommand"] = scrollbar.set

Status = Text(okno, bg="white", height="3",width="12", font="Arial",)
Status.insert(END, "Status: ","status")
Status.tag_config("status",font="Arial 20")
Status.tag_config("online", foreground="green")
Status.tag_config("offline", foreground="red")
Status.config(state=DISABLED)

def spustitServer():
    global Status
    global Log
    global klienti
    global host
    global port

    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(10)
    Status.config(state=NORMAL)
    Status.insert(END,"Online","online")
    Status.config(state=DISABLED)
    Log.config(state=NORMAL)
    Log.insert(END,"\nServer je nyni Online!")
    Log.config(state=DISABLED)

    while 1:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        Log.config(state=NORMAL)
        Log.insert(END,"\n[{0}] :: Pripojen:   {1}".format(time.ctime(time.time()),str(addr)))
        Log.config(state=DISABLED)
        if addr not in klienti:
            klienti.append(c)

        thread.start_new_thread(uzivatel_thread,(c,klienti))

def uzivatel_thread(c,klienti):
    global Log

    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if "/konec" in data:
            klienti.remove(c)
        elif not data:
            break
        else:
            Log.config(state=NORMAL)
            Log.insert(END,"\n[{0}] :: {1} ::  {2}".format(time.ctime(time.time()),str(addr),str(data)))
            Log.config(state=DISABLED)
            for klient in klienti:
                klient.sendall(data)

def stopServer():
    global Log
    global Status

    Status.config(state=NORMAL)
    Status.insert(END,"Offline","offline")
    Status.config(state=DISABLED)
    Log.config(state=NORMAL)
    Log.insert(END,"\nServer je nyni Offline!")
    Log.config(state=DISABLED)
    c.close()
    s.close()
    thread.close()



startTlacitko = Button(okno, font=20, text="Start", width="12", height="5",   bd=0, bg="#ff0000", activebackground="#ff3333",command=spustitServer)
stopTlacitko = Button(okno, font=20, text="Stop", width="12", height="5", bd=0, bg="#ff0000", activebackground="#ff3333",command=stopServer)


Log.place(x=6,y=6, height=382, width=676)
scrollbar.place(x=682,y=6, height=382)
Status.place(x=6, y=410, height=40, width=250)
startTlacitko.place(x=262, y=410, height=40)
stopTlacitko.place(x=380, y=410, height=40)


okno.mainloop()
```

I know it's terrible code.

So this server is working in console but I wanted to have it in tkinter and it isn't working pretty well.

Comment: So if you now it's terrible, why don't you rewrite it? If you still don't understand, remove unrelated parts, provide more information. You're supposed to ask a bit more generic questions which may help not only you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for reply!